# Rejecting error after opening `.catch`

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

Are these two code blocks the same? I'm looking to open up `.catch()` and log the error but I still want the error to be "uncaught", can I just return it? Or does it need to be wrapped in a `Promise.reject()`?

Block A:

```
soSomething()
    .then(() => {
        return "meow"
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log(err)
        return err
    })
```

Block B:

```
soSomething()
    .then(() => {
        return "meow"
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

The two patterns are not the same.

The first handles the error and returns a resolved `Promise`, reaching the first function parameter at a  chained `.then()`.

The second example returns a rejected `Promise`, reaching the second function parameter at a chained `.then()` or `.catch()`.

> I'm looking to open up `.catch()` and log the error but I still want
>   the error to be "uncaught", can I just return it?

The first pattern should meet requirement.

Comment: Though note, `err` is not defined at either example